# Why does UILabel.text result in “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I've read several answers to this question and have tried all recommendations with no success.  I'm fairly new to swift and am building an app with Swift, PHP and MySQL. I'm receiving the error after the user has logged in to the app and the system should be displaying the username via a label using `UILabel.text`.  The error is occurring on setting a value to the `UILabel.text` variable.  My code is included below.  I've tried to hardcode values on other pages and am getting this error throughout my project.

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet var usernameLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set global variables
        let username = (user!["username"] as AnyObject).uppercased

        // label values
        print(usernameLbl ?? username!)
        usernameLbl.text = username
    }
}
```

I'm accessing the HomeViewController programmatically.  The app uses a tab bar and the first page of it is Home.  The code is from a course I'm taking on Udemy.  Here is how I'm accessing Home:

```
// func to pass to home page or to tabBar
func login() {

    // refer to our Main.storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // store our tabBar Object from Main.storyboard in tabBar var
    let tabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar")

    // present tabBar that is storing in tabBar var
    window?.rootViewController = tabBar

}
```

Comment: I've already verified that user has a value.  It's usernameLbl that's nil.

Comment: Thanks Rob. The outlets are hooked up.  HomeviewController is not the initial, it's accessed programmatically.

Comment: Then perhaps show us how you programmatically instantiated it. Make sure you (a) give this storyboard a name and use [`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller), and not just `HomeViewController()`. Also, I find it exceedingly unlikely that this is really a `UITabBarController` with an `@IBOutlet`. Don't conflate the tab bar controller (which presents tabs to access child view controllers) and the child view controllers themselves. They're completely different things.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a little. So, that how you instantiate the tab bar controller. But isn't the label on one of the child view controllers (one that is a `UIViewController` subclass, not a `UITabBarController` subclass)?

Comment: @Rob - It worked!  Your answer regarding the UITabController being questionable is what worked.  I changed it to UIViewController and things are now working as programmed. Thanks so much.  You rock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing an `@IBOutlet` on a `UITabBarController` is very suspicious. You generally have a tab bar controller which presents child `UIViewController` subclasses, and put labels on those child view controllers, not the tab bar controller. A tab bar controller does not generally have `IBOutlet` references. The child view controllers would have them.

Double check to which class you've connected that `@IBOutlet` and confirm whether it's a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to follow best practices and avoid the use of `!` as much as possible.

The error you've got happens when you try to access a value or reference stored in an optional that **does not contain any value** (i.e., it is `nil`).

In your case, if `usernameLbl` is `nil`, `usernameLbl.text` will crash your app (Think "null pointer exception" in Java, perhaps?).

It is very common to define outlests as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
```

...instead of the safer:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel?
```

...because the first one allows you to access its properties without using the `?` (i.e. `label.text` vs. `label?.text`). But there's an implicit assumption that **the label is not nil**: the `!` by itself does nothing to prevent this (it only silences the compiler, telling it "I know what I'm doing, trust me!").

That shouldn't be a problem as long as you only access it **after** `viewDidLoad()` **and** your outlets are proerly connected in Interface Builder/storyboard, because in that case it will be guaranteed to not be `nil`.

**My guess is that you forgot to hook up the outlet to your label.**

Here is [a tutorial on storyboards](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_storyboards.htm) in case it helps.

---

The whole reason outlets need to be defined as optionals (implicitly unwrapped `!` or "standard" `?`) is that in Swift, all properties must have a value by the time the instance is initialized (actually, even before calling the super class initializer if that applies).

For view controllers, instance initialization happens before the subviews can be initialized and assigned to the properties/outlets. That happens in the method `loadView()`, which is called lazily (only just before the view is actually needed for display). So by making all subviews optional (and variable, not  constant), they can have the temporary "value" of `nil` by the time the initializer completes execution (thus satisfying Swift's rules).

---

**Edit:** If your outlet is still `nil` at runtime even though it is connected in interface builder, you can at least try to intercept any code resetting it and see what's going on, with a **property observer**:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        if label == nil {
            print("Label set to nil!") 
            // ^ SET A BREAKPOINT IN THIS LINE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas.  I've changed the ! to ? and although the app no longer crashes, it still does not display the value of the UILabel. text in the app.  I've also printed out the value of 'username' in my error log to ensure it is not nil, however usernameLbl is nil and I can't force it to take a value.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Like I said at the end of my answer, **Make sure your outlet var is connected to the label in the storyboard**. You do know how to do that, right? Set the actual subclass of your view controller (not the default  "UIViewController") in the Identifty inpsector, and control-drag from the label to the view controller.

Comment: I've already verified that the outlet var is connected to the storyboard.

Comment: If the outlet is properly connected and you are accessing the label within (or after) `viewDidLoad()`, it should not be `nil`. Make sure it is the proper storyboard/view controller...

Comment: If `usernameLbl` is nil then the outlet must not be connected, or something is changing it to nil. The most likely explanation, though, is that it is **not** connected even though you think it is.

Comment: I've gone through all recommendations and verified my steps of connecting the outlets.  Everything is connected.  Any other suggestions.

Comment: Check your view controller's code to make siure there is no `usernameLbl = nil` assignment. Check the other source files for assignments like `viewController.usernameLbl = nil`. See my edit

Comment: @techgirl08 - Alternatively, if you are confident that the outlet is hooked up on the tab bar controller (weird), then the other reason that outlets don't get connected if you programmatically instantiated the `HomeViewController` incorrectly (e.g. if you did `HomeViewController()` anywhere).

Comment: @Rob That is the most likely possibility, now that I think about it. We never asked the OP how they are instantiating the VC (segue, programmatically from `UIStoryboard.instantiate...`, using `init()`, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

Think of the `!` operator as the "crash if nil" operator. It's *actually* called the "force unwrap" operator, and is used to "unwrap" an Optional. If the optional contains a nil, it triggers the same error as trying to dereference a null pointer in other languages.

You should avoid the `!` operator until you really understand what it does.

IB (Interface Builder) sets up outlets as force-unwrapped so that you can reference them without having to constantly check them for nil. The idea is that your outlets should never be nil, and if they are it's a problem and you WANT to crash. Think of it as a fuse. It triggers an obvious, early failure that's easy to find and fix.

Having a broken outlet (or missing IBAction) is one of the easiest mistakes to make. With an outlet declared as

```
@IBOutlet var someOutlet: UILabel!
```

The compiler lets you reference it without unwrapping it, but you will crash if the outlet is nil.

You can avoid the force-unwrap by adding a `?` after the outlet name, or using and `if let` or a guard statement.

However, with outlets, the thing to do is to realize you've got a broken outlet and just fix it. Then your code works fine.

To fix a broken outlet, control-drag from IB to the `@IBoutlet` declaration in your code. Think of it as hooking up a cable in your entertainment system.

When you declare an outlet in your code the editor puts a little open circle in the margin to the left of the `@IBOutlet` declaration. When the outlet is connected, the editor shows a filled-in circle, so it's easy to see if an outlet is connected or not. (Same with `@IBAction` methods.)

Comment: Thanks Duncan.  I've verified that the connection exist (the editor shows a filled-in circle) and I've reconnected it to ensure it's there.  I just tried a test on another page of the app and am getting the same error.  Are there any configurations I should check.